# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3D array and would like to make a 2D plot using [`plt.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) but I keep getting the error

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

My `x` and `y` arrays are both of length 59 and the `z` array is length 59*59=3481 since `x` and `y` is now a matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

points = [(54.5, 17.041667, 31.993), (54.5, 17.083333, 31.911), (54.458333, 17.041667, 31.945), (54.458333, 17.083333, 31.866)]
points = sorted(points)               # order points by x, then by y
(x1, y1, q11), (_x1, y2, q12), (x2, _y1, q21), (_x2, _y2, q22) = points

interp2d=[]

nums = np.linspace(x1, x2, num = 60, endpoint=True)
numms = np.linspace(y1, y2, num = 60, endpoint=True)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(nums[:-1], numms[:-1], indexing='xy')

for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    for j in range(len(numms)-1):
        x=nums[i]
        y=numms[j]

            interp = (q11 * (x2 - x) * (y2 - y) +
        q21 * (x - x1) * (y2 - y) +
        q12 * (x2 - x) * (y - y1) +
        q22 * (x - x1) * (y - y1)
       ) / ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) + 0.0)

        interp2d.append(interp)

interp2d = np.asarray(interp2d)     
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True)    

ax2.pcolormesh(X,Y,interp2d, cmap=plt.cm.BuPu_r)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't show all of your code, just the relevant bit(s).

Comment: I'm guessing you just need to `interp2d.reshape(len(nums)-1, len(numms)-1)` (after `np.asarray(interp2d)`) to make it 2D like your `X` and `Y`, but I am unable to test at this time.

Comment: Thanks @Engineero. That solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of interp2d are expected to be 2D array. So, you might wanna look into that. Rest of the code is irrelevant to the question you asked. So, good luck!

[image: pcolormesh]